# AngularJs $http service return entire document body instead of specifice data

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following AngularJs code to retrieve data from another page. But instead of getting a specific data (i.e. there is only a paragraph "Hello Angular" on page 'testphp.php') , it shows entire document of page starting from **<!DOCTYPE> html** to **</html>** 
here is code

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,$http) {
 $http.get("testlocal.php").then(function(response) {
  $scope.testfile = response.data;
 });
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>{{testfile}}</p>
</div>
```

**Note:** this example was demonstrated on w3schools.com. and there , this code is working.

Comment: I would think that it depends on what `testlocal.php` sends

Comment: You should mention action name instead of file name in $http get method.

Comment: can you share w3schools.com example link?

Comment: You are getting `HTML` output coz php when executed returns HTML output. In order to make `testlocal.php` work it should return `json` and for that you have to create a json and echo it.

Comment: here is link of example explained at w3schools.com https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_http_get

Comment: It is not pure html, it is just a string, that is why they simply use `{{testfile}}` instead of `ng-bind-html='testfile'`